# Processing form data without nonce verification Error on my Function - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, travis-ci, nonce

Here is my function:

```
public function save_meta( $term_id = 0, $taxonomy = '' ) {
    $meta = ! empty( $_POST['banner'] ) ? $_POST['banner'] : '';

    if ( empty( $meta ) ) {
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, 'banner' );
    } else {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'banner', $meta );
    }
}
```

And When Travis review the code it tells me that 
Processing form data without nonce verification.
     |       | (WordPress.CSRF.NonceVerification.NoNonceVerification)

I tried the following but is not working:

```
public function save_meta( $term_id = 0, $taxonomy = '' ) {
    $meta = ! empty( $_POST['banner'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['banner'] ) ? $_POST['banner'] : '';

    if ( empty( $meta ) ) {
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, 'banner' );
    } else {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'banner', $meta );
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: how do you call your function? where is your html and js code?

Answer (score 0):

The nonce is a hash of the user id, the session token, the current time and a tag generated by the function wp_create_nonce(). This hash is used to validate that the request is not conterfeit. In your case a suitable tag would be 'update-banner_' . $term_id. Your HTTP request should return this nonce as a query or post parameter. For form submission this is usually done by using a hidden field in the form. WordPress provides the convenience function wp_nonce_field() to do this. Your request handler should then verify this nonce using the function wp_verify_nonce() or the convenience function check_admin_referer(). Please read the WordPress documentation for details on calling these functions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I did read the documentation and that is why I came up with the wp_verify_nonce part, please ready a the second block of code and let me know

Comment: wp_verify_nonce() should be called on the return value of wp_create_nonce(). Did you read https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces? Note that a nonce has a value like 796c7766b1. What is the value of your $_POST['banner']? In particular. a valid nonce is never just ''.